# Best and most efficient way to capture spreadsheet data

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have a spreadsheet that has data like this

```
Group,Region,Market
G7,EMEA,Germany
G7,NA,Canada
G7,APAC,Japan
```

What is the most efficient way to capture this information?
I use a dictionary to store this information as {Group: {Region : Market} }

and the code I have is

```
    try:
        with open(fileName) as sourceFile:
            for line in sourceFile:
                if not headerRow:
                    for group, region, market in [line.rstrip().split(",")]:
                        if group in self.REGIONAL_MARKETS:
                            self.REGIONAL_MARKETS[group].update({int(region):market})
                        else:
                            self.REGIONAL_MARKETS.update({group:{int(region):market}})
                headerRow=False
            return self.REGIONAL_MARKETS
    except IOError as e:
        print("Invalid File Name. Message = "%(e))
```

Thanks for your inputs

Comment: Use [`csv module`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1. Your `try` block is too big (the shorter the better, as it means more specific error handling); and
2. You could use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to simplify the creation of your output data structure.

Try something like:

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = defaultdict(dict)

try:
    with open(fileName) as sourceFile:
        header = sourceFile.readline() # skip header
        lines = sourceFile.readlines() # get the rest of the data
except IOError as e:
    print("Invalid File Name. Message = "%(e))
else:
    for line in lines:
        group, region, market = line.rstrip().split(",") # don't iterate over a
                                                         # single-element list
        data[group].update({region: market}) # how is e.g. 'EMEA' an integer?
```

On your test data, this gives me:

```
>>> data
defaultdict(<type 'dict'>, {'G7': {'NA': 'Canada', 
                                   'EMEA': 'Germany', 
                                   'APAC': 'Japan'}})
```

Additionally, look into [`csv.DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader), which will do some of the file processing work for you.